# `password_reset_confirm.html` with AngularJS won't submit

Tags: angularjs, django

I want to integrate AngularJS in my custom `password_reset_confirm.html` template in Django. But when I fill out a new password and hit "submit," nothing happens.

I have this in my custom `password_reset_confirm.html` template:

```
{% block main %}
    <div class="elems-wrapper card bg-light elem-with-margin-top membership-detail-elem" ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl"> 
        <div class="card-body">
            <h2 class="card-title">{% trans "Reset password" %}</h2>
            {% if validlink %}
                <form id="reset-pw-confirm-form" name="newPWForm" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input 
                            id="id_new_password1"
                            class="form-control"
                            type="[[[ newPW.showPW ? 'text' : 'password' ]]]"
                            name="new_password1"
                            aria-label="Enter new password"
                            placeholder="Enter new password" 
                            ng-model="newPW.pw"
                            ng-minlength="8" 
                            ng-maxlength="32"
                            required>
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <div class="input-group-text">
                                <input 
                                    aria-label="Checkbox for showing password" 
                                    type="checkbox" 
                                    ng-model="newPW.showPW" 
                                    ng-checked="false"
                                >
                                <small class="text-muted">[[[ newPW.showPW ? 'Hide' : 'Show' ]]]</small>
                            </div>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ng-disabled="!newPW.pw">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input 
                        id="id_new_password2"
                        type="hidden"
                        value="[[[ newPW ]]]"
                        name="new_password2"
                        aria-label="Automatically enters password a second time for confirmation"
                        placeholder="Enter again" 
                        ng-model="newPW"
                        ng-minlength="8" 
                        ng-maxlength="32"                       
                        required>
                </form>
            {% else %}
                <p>{% trans "The password reset link was invalid, possibly because it has already been used. Please request a new password reset." %}</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock main %}
```

And this in my JS file:

```
var app=    angular.module("app",[]);
app.config(function($interpolateProvider, $httpProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol("[[[");
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol("]]]");

    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName=  "csrftoken";
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName=  "X-CSRFToken";
});

app.controller("Ctrl", function($scope, $http){

});
```

How do I make the form submit to the correct path for setting my new password when I hit the "submit" button?

**UPDATE** I added `action="{% url 'password_reset_confirm' %}"` to my `form` and now I get an error.

1. First I go to `password_reset/` and enter my email.
2. I check the email in my inbox and click the link to go reset my password: e.g. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/reset/MQ/4uq-4fdadaa29b99110fcccb/`
3. I see the following error.

   NoReverseMatch at /reset/MQ/4uq-4fdadaa29b99110fcccb/
   Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'reset/(?P[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P.+)/$']

The offending line is this: `<form id="reset-pw-confirm-form" name="newPWForm" method="post" action="{% url 'password_reset_confirm' %}">`

Here's some code from my `urls.py`:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.i18n import set_language

from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from mezzanine.core.views import direct_to_template
from mezzanine.conf import settings

from theme import views

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns += [
    url("^map-types/$", views.get_map_types, name="map_types"),
    url("^searched-location/$", views.insert_searched_location, name="searched_location"),
    url("^geoms/$", views.get_geoms, name="get_geoms"),
    url("^single-geom/$", views.get_single_geom_data, name="single_geom_data"),
    url("^email-check/$", views.email_check, name="email_check"),
    url("^login-register/$", views.login_register, name="login_register"),
    url("^membership/$", views.membership, name="membership"),
    url("^member/$", views.member, name="member"),
    url("^change-email/$", views.change_email, name="change_email"),
    url("^change-password/$", views.change_pw, name="change_pw"),
    url("^change-cc/$", views.change_cc, name="change_cc"),
    url("^change-plan/$", views.change_plan, name="change_plan"),
    url("^cancel-plan/$", views.cancel_plan, name="cancel_plan"),
    url("^logout/$", views.log_out, name="logout"),
    url(r'^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url("^", include("mezzanine.urls")),
]
```

Comment: The issue is with your main `urls.py` can you please include them?

Comment: @BorkoKovacev I included the `urls.py ` that's in my Django project `myProject/myProject/urls.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`password_reset_confirm` requires two arguments (`uuidb64` and `token`) which you are not supplying to the `url` template tag, hence the `NoReverseMatch` error.

Rather than trying to reconstruct the URL with `reverse` it would be easier just to change your form `action` to point to the current URL (that is what you need to post the form to):

```
<!-- empty action means use the current URL - alternatively omit this attribute altogether -->
<form id="reset-pw-confirm-form" name="newPWForm" method="post" action="">
```

If for some reason you do want to reconstruct the URL manually then you'd need to do something like this:

```
{% url 'password_reset_confirm` uuidb64=request.view.kwargs.uuidb64 token=request.view.kwargs.token %}
```

... but that really isn't necessary IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Either:

1. Provide an `action="/<reset-password-url>"` in your form or
2. Provide a click event in your `submit` button `ng-click=submit()` and implement the `submit()` function in your controller that will submit the details. If you use this option remove `method="post"` in your form.

   `$scope.submit = function () {
         $http.post('<resert-password-url>', <the-request>).then(function(){...})
     }`

Comment: I added `action="{% url 'password_reset_confirm' %}"` to my code and got an error. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

The path you're sending cannot be interpreted.

Add `url(r'^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))` to your `urls.py` towards the end or import the individual reset view from `auth_views` as you've defined them.

Comment: Edited my answer with your suggestion, but still am getting this error